# Set font color in a tr() function

Tags: qt, qt4

I am thinking of changing the color of some text in a tr() function.I am thinking of

```
tableModel->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("<font color=red><i>Org. Name</i></font>"));
```

Will it be possible to change the font color?.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that providing an HTML string will change the appearence of the text and even if it works it is not the best approach to mix the content with the styling. You should  use [stylesheets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/stylesheet.html) and change the color of the [header view](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview) of your `QTableView`.

```
QString styleSheet = "QHeaderView::section {"
                        "color: red;"
                        "background-color: black; }";

tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

Comment: Thanks all.It seems its going to take more work than i thought since  subclassing QHeaderView and reimplementing paint() is what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the whole HTML string will be offered for translation, including the markup. If you want translators to mess with the HTML, your approach just works. Usually one wouldn't want translators to mess with (and possibly break) the HTML markup, then one would use something like this:

```
QString::fromLatin1("<font color=red><i>%1</i></font>").arg(tr("Org. Name"))
```

I.e. mark only the actual text for translation, instad of the whole html string.